# How to swap the position of siblings in xml using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, swap, siblings, xmlstarlet

I have the following xml file that I would like to swap the positions of the two siblings ("firstname" and "surname"):

From:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
    <name>
     <firstname>Peter</firstname>
     <surname>Frenchman</surname>
    </name>
    <name>
     <firstname>Betty</firstname>
     <surname>Jones</surname>
    </name>
</article>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
    <name>
     <surname>Frenchman</surname>
     <firstname>Peter</firstname>   
    </name>
    <name>
     <surname>Jones</surname>
     <firstname>Betty</firstname>
    </name>
</article>
```

This is what I did:

I created a temp element (surname1) and copy the values from "surname" to it. The xmlstarlet command did not do the work:

```
xmlstarlet ed  -L   -i "//article/name/givenname" -t elem -n "surname1" -v "$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v  "//article/name/surname" swapelment.xml)" swapelment.xml
```

Comment: It is better to use xmlstarlet and XSLT for the task

Answer (score 1):

Using `xmlstarlet edit` to move an XML element to a specified position
can be done like this:

1. insert a new empty node as destination, `-i` for a preceding sibling,
   `-a` for a following sibling
2. copy the contents of source to the new node
3. delete source after copying

For an input file containing a series of `name` elements, each with a
`firstname` and a `surname` child element, swopping all can be done
like this:

```sh
# shellcheck  shell=sh  disable=SC2016
xmlstarlet edit \
  --var F '*/name/surname' \
  -i '$F/preceding-sibling::*[1]' -t 'elem' -n 'surname' \
  -u '$prev' -x 'following-sibling::surname[1]/node() | following-sibling::surname[1]/@*' \
  -d '$F' \
file.xml
```

where:

- the multi-member source node-set is referenced by variable `F`
- `-i …` inserts a `surname` before each `firstname` in `$F`
  (`firstname` being the first
  [preceding sibling](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes) element of `surname`)
- `-x` specifies a relative XPath expression to handle the multi-member
  node-set in `$F`, the context node being the newly created `surname`
  which should duplicate its first
  [following sibling](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#axes) `surname`
- `-x '…/node() | …/@*'` makes a deep copy of source's nodes on the
  child and attribute
  [axes](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-AxisSpecifier) (using a
  [union](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#NT-UnionExpr)) -- since `surname` doesn't actually
  have any attributes  `| …/@*` can be omitted
- `-d '$F'` deletes the original `surname`s, after copying

`--var` defines a named variable, and the back reference `prev` (aka
`xstar:prev`) variable refers to the node(s) created by the most
recent `-s`, `-i`, or `-a` option which all define or redefine it
(see [`xmlstarlet.txt`](https://fossies.org/linux/xmlstarlet/doc/xmlstarlet.txt) for examples of
`--var` and `$prev`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to implement it via XSLT.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

XMLStarlet natively supports XSLT transformation: [XMLStarlet Overview](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)

Usage: `xml tr <xsl-file> <xml-file-or-uri>`

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
    <name>
        <firstname>Peter</firstname>
        <surname>Frenchman</surname>
    </name>
    <name>
        <firstname>Betty</firstname>
        <surname>Jones</surname>
    </name>
</article>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IdentityTransform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="surname"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="firstname"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<article>
  <name>
    <surname>Frenchman</surname>
    <firstname>Peter</firstname>
  </name>
  <name>
    <surname>Jones</surname>
    <firstname>Betty</firstname>
  </name>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak. It works. I am learning xmlstarlet and I want the swap also done in xmlstarlet.

Comment: XMLStarlet natively supports XSLT transformation. I added it to the answer. XSLT method is much simpler vs. direct Edit option.